# Date Conversion in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling to convert a bunch of dates in Google Sheets.

My dates are in the format mentioned in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48x72.png).

Some dates have AM/PM in them, while some have a / instead of a -.

I need to convert them to yyyy"-"mm"-"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss while converting the time to 24hour format in case of PM.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that most of your data uses the American date convention `m/d/yyyy` while your spreadsheet uses the Indian `d/m/yyyy` date convention. But then again, some of the data appears to already be in the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format you are requesting as the result format. To convert all the dates, use this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isnumber(A2:A) + isblank(A2:A), 
    A2:A, 
    regexreplace(A2:A, "^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)(.+)", "$3-$1-$2$4") + 0 
  ) 
)
```

Format the result cells as **Format > Number > Date time** or as the custom format you mentioned. See the new Solution column in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qE20G95RY6u4e-VsEA1oB2a0C0N8pCowGmzcSbeeuQo/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Hi @doubleunary I tried that using Erik's suggestion. I get the error "DATEVALUE parameter '04/15/2021 02:03:29 PM' cannot be parsed to date/time."

Also I noticed that values in column A2:A are considered incorrectly by Google Sheets. For example, the data on A74 is actually April 12th 2021. But Google Sheets is recgnizing it as December 4th 2021.

I created a public Sheet if you wanna have a look.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qE20G95RY6u4e-VsEA1oB2a0C0N8pCowGmzcSbeeuQo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your raw data is in A2:A. Clear B2:B and place the following into B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A2:A&"")+TIMEVALUE(A2:A&""),DATEVALUE(A2:A)+TIMEVALUE(A2:A))))`

This formula has error control built in, to handle the raw data if there is a mix of strings and real date-times.

Next, select the entire Column B. Apply **Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format** and enter the following in the text field at the top: *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss*

Comment: Hi @erik-tyler,

I tried that. It gives me the error "DATEVALUE parameter '04/15/2021 02:03:29 PM' cannot be parsed to date/time."

Also I noticed that values in column A2:A are considered incorrectly by Google Sheets. For example, the data on A74 is actually April 12th 2021. But Google Sheets is recgnizing it as December 4th 2021.

I created a public Sheet if you wanna have a look.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qE20G95RY6u4e-VsEA1oB2a0C0N8pCowGmzcSbeeuQo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see that you have a working solution column now in place. So it looks like you are all set. As others have noted, the problem arose because of incompatibility between date formatting in US and in your locale.

Comment: That's right Erik! Thanks a lot for your help.